Extensions of Hardy's Inequality for Tail Sums
I have been studying various formulations of Hardy's inequality, inspired by notable theorems from works like those of Paul Richard Beesack and others. A particular theorem that caught my attention describes integrating functions over different ranges based on parameter values:
$$
\text{Theorem: If } p>1, r \neq 1, f(x) \geqq 0, \text{ and } F(x) \text{ is defined by }
$$
$$
F(x)= \begin{cases}
\int_0^x f(t) \, dt & (r>1), \\
\int_x^{\infty} f(t) \, dt & (r<1),
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\text{then }
\int_0^\infty x^{-r} F^p \, dx < \left(\frac{p}{|r-1|}\right)^p \int_0^\infty x^{-r}(x f)^p \, dx,
\text{ unless } f \equiv 0. \text{ The constant }\left(\frac{p}{|r-1|}\right) \text{ is the best possible.}
$$
Given this, I'm interested in adaptations of Hardy's inequality that might apply to the $\textbf{tail sums}$ of sequences, specifically those that could provide concrete bounds using a specified constant $C$. For instance, consider bounding the following expression:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left(\sum_{i=n}^\infty x_i^2\right)^{1/2},
$$
Here, $\{x_i\}$ is a monotone decreasing sequence with $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i < \infty$. This type of setting challenges typical applications of Hardy's inequality and primarily focuses on sums from the start to an index $n$, not from an index $n$ to infinity.

$\textbf{Are there known extensions of Hardy’s inequality}$ incorporating a constant $C$ to provide bounds for such tail sums involving sequences? This might involve a theoretical derivation where $C$ adjusts based on the decay characteristics of the sequence or dependent other parameters
$\textbf{What form might these generalizations take?}$ For instance, could we expect a generalized inequality like:
$$
   \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{i=n}^\infty x_i^2\right)^{p/2} \leq C \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^p,
   $$
with specific values or bounds for $C$ depending on $p$ and the nature of the sequence decay?

Any further insights, rigorous proofs, or references related to such generalizations or potential extensions of Hardy’s inequality that effectively handle tail sums of sequences would be good to know.
